# Is there a one-line way to call a lambda function on a collection?

Tags: c++, boost, groovy, stl

In Groovy I can work with collections like so:

```
["a", "b"].each { println(it) }
[1, 2].collect { it * 2 }.grep { it % 3}.each { println(it) }
```

Is there an equivalent syntax for C++11/14?

```
Collection({"a", "b"}).Each([](auto i) { printf("%s\n", i); });
Collection({1, 2}).
  Collect([](auto i) { return i * 2; }).
  Grep([](auto i) { return i % 3; }).
  Each([](auto i) { printf("%d\n", i); };
Range(0, maxIdx). // ...
```

I'm wondering if I can do it with a new class like this or if there's already something like this that I'm not aware of. I'm a bit stumped about what the implementation would even look like, particularly for chaining function calls like that. Thanks!

Comment: This reminds me of [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3)

Comment: This one `std::for_each`?  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each

Comment: the c++ standard library has the functions to do these steps, but not in a chaining form. However, there's nothing to stop this type of syntax from existing

Comment: `for(auto& i: {"a", "b"}}) { /* do stuff to i here */ }`

Comment: I never thought I'd see someone using `printf` in a lambda function in C++. Go figure.

Comment: I admit, it's funny to see. We don't use STL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a sampling of range libraries:

### Range V3

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3jjuHY7G1r4aTSRw)</kbd>**

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std::string_literals;
using namespace ranges::v3;
using std::vector;

int main() {
    auto print = [](auto const& v) { std::cout << v << "\n"; };

    for(auto sz : { "a", "b" }) print(sz);
    for_each({"a", "b"}, print);

    vector v { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    auto chain = 
           view::transform([](auto i) { return i*2; })
         | view::filter([](auto i) -> bool { return i % 3; });

    for_each(v | chain, print);

    auto constexpr Range = view::iota;
    for_each(Range(12, 24) | chain, print);
}
```

Prints

```
a
b
a
b
2
4
8
10
26
28
32
34
38
40
44
46
```

### Boost Range

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tWlPezLKx0K1eEFz)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace boost::adaptors;
using std::vector;

int main() {
    auto print = [](auto const& v) { std::cout << v << "\n"; };

    for(auto sz : { "a", "b" }) print(sz);
    boost::for_each(vector {"a", "b"}, print);

    vector v { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    boost::for_each(v
            | transformed([](auto i) { return i*2; })
            | filtered([](auto i) -> bool { return i % 3; }),
         print);

    for_each(boost::irange(12, 24) 
            | transformed([](auto i) { return i*2; })
            | filtered([](auto i) -> bool { return i % 3; }),
        print);
}
```

> Note that we don't store the expression template because Boost's
>   facilities don't deal well with temporaries (Range v3 generates
>   compilation errors on unsafe use).

Prints

```
a
b
a
b
2
4
8
10
26
28
32
34
38
40
44
46
```

### For Sheer Fun

You can do the same using various Boost libraries in pure C++03:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](https://wandbox.org/permlink/x4JS2EqzPQi1Lwot)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::adaptors;
using namespace boost::phoenix::arg_names;
using std::vector;

int main() {
    char const* ab[] = { "a", "b" };
    // who needs c++11 for ranged-for?
    BOOST_FOREACH(char const* sz, ab) std::cout << sz << "\n";

    // who needs c++11 for lambdas?
    boost::for_each(ab, std::cout << arg1 << "\n");

    // who needs c++11 for initializer lists?
    vector<int> v;
    using boost::assign::operator+=; // very dubious magic, but hey, we're having fun
    v += 1, 2, 3, 4, 5;

    // etc.
    boost::for_each(v | transformed(arg1 * 2) | filtered(arg1 % 3), std::cout << arg1 << "; ");
    std::cout << '\n';

    boost::for_each(boost::irange(12, 24) | transformed(arg1 * 2) | filtered(arg1 % 3), std::cout << arg1 << "; ");
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Prints

```
a
b
a
b
2; 4; 8; 10; 
26; 28; 32; 34; 38; 40; 44; 46;
```

Comment: Added Boost Range. Also in [C++11](https://wandbox.org/permlink/V4XPylrXz5ZbHDcI) and [C++03](https://wandbox.org/permlink/x4JS2EqzPQi1Lwot) here.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you! I don't quite get how the answer has 6 upvotes, yet the question has 0.

Answer (score 1):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), it would be something like:

```
for (auto e : v
              | ranges::view::transform([](int n){ return 2 * n; })
              | ranges::view::filter([](int n){ return i % 3; }) )
{
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
}
```